# Add Customize posts edit links to selectively refreshed partials

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using the [Customize Posts](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts) and [Customize Object Selector](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-object-selector) plugins with the WordPress Customizer.

The Customize Posts edit links show for the posts in the preview on initial page load but don't get applied to partials added to the page via selective refresh. Is there a way that I can add the edit links to my refreshed partials?

I'm using settings created with php as well as dynamically created JavaScript settings. Here's a quick example of the settings created with php:

```
namespace MyTheme\Customizer;

add_filter( 'customize_register', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\register', 30 );

function register( \WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'theme_options', array(
        'title'    => __( 'Theme options', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority' => 130, // Before Additional CSS.
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'selected_posts', array(
        'default'           => [],
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\\sanitize_ids',
    ) );

    $selected_posts = new \CustomizeObjectSelector\Control( $wp_customize, 'selected_posts', array(
        'label' => __( 'Posts', 'mytheme' ),
        'section' => 'theme_options',
        'post_query_vars' => array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ),
        'select2_options' => array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'allowClear' => true,
            'placeholder' => __( '— Select —', 'default' ),
        ),
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( $selected_posts );

    $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'selected_posts', array(
        'selector' => '.editorsPicks',
        'render_callback' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\\customize_partial_selected_posts',
        'container_inclusive' => true,
        'fallback_refresh' => false,
    ) );
}

/**
 * Sanitize IDs
 *
 * @param array $ids An array of IDs.
 * @return array A sanitized array of IDs.
 */
function sanitize_ids( $ids ) {
    return array_map( 'intval', $ids );
}

function customize_partial_selected_posts() {
    get_template_part( 'partials/layouts/editors-picks' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize Posts recognizes post field partials as defined by selectors in [`WP_Customize_Posts_Preview::get_post_field_partial_schema()`](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/blob/135bc5bdcf2635b05c231b9a4c8aabaf52d1d68d/php/class-wp-customize-posts-preview.php#L1304-L1398) combined by looking for the [closest `.hentry` or `.post-{id}` elements](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/blob/135bc5bdcf2635b05c231b9a4c8aabaf52d1d68d/js/customize-post-field-partial.js#L181-L185). So as long as the posts in your `editors-picks` partials make use of the `post_class()` function for each element's container and the other microformats like `.entry-title` for the child elements, then the post field partials should automatically get added. Take for example my child theme of Twenty Seventeen in how it defines the [`content-excerpt.php`](https://github.com/westonruter/twentyseventeen-westonson/blob/master/template-parts/post/content-excerpt.php) template part and how that template part gets [included](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/2c1858a8c3f6e6d8dfe1efe57cfca4b658094b41/src/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/page/content-front-page-panels.php#L53-L73).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Weston and for all your contributions to the customizer :) I had manually added the `.hentry`, `.post-{id}` and `.entry-title` classes in my partial. This worked for the initial preview but not the refresh. Looking at your answer I tried using `post_class()` and worked out that it also needed the `.type-post` class.